# QGIS Clipping Raster ERROR Cutline polygon is invalid

Tags: qgis, clip

I want to clip a raster tif image based on a shapefile. However,the error as Fig.2 popuped when I use the Clipper Toolbox.What's the reason?I can make it in ArcGIS by Clip function in Toolbox.Thanks.

[image]

```
              Fig.1
```

[image]

```
             Fig.2
```

Comment: You're right.There are several self intersection indeed.I have solved the problem.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously you are using a polygon which has a self intersection.

Check your geometries in QGIS with `Vector > Geometry Tools > Check validity`.